# Paypal Payment Pro 3-D Secure PHP

Tags: php, paypal, 3d-secure

I have been trying to implement Payment Pro 3D secure, but stuck at a point. I followed the documentation provided by Paypal. But I guess I am in need of some serious guidance.

I got nothing but the html response of below displayed form in issuer authentication response.

[image]

When I try to submit the form, URL redirects to:
http://localhost/dodirect3d/NextV3DSRequest;jsessionid=Yc8GvrWh2KcnMK1Y

I have used the class files provided by CardinalCommerce Corporation.

Below is the procedure I followed:

```
<h1>CheckOut</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <td><input type="number" name="Amount" value="10000"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Card Number</th>
            <td><input type="number" name="CardNumber" value="4000000000000002"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Expiry Date</th>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="CardExpMonth" placeholder="MM" value="01"> 
                /
                <input type="number" name="CardExpYear" placeholder="YYYY" value="2016"> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
if ($_POST) {
    require('CentinelClient.php');
    require('CentinelConfig.php');
    require('CentinelUtility.php');

    $centinelClient = new CentinelClient;

    $centinelClient->add("MsgType", "cmpi_lookup");
    $centinelClient->add("Version", CENTINEL_MSG_VERSION);
    $centinelClient->add("ProcessorId", CENTINEL_PROCESSOR_ID);
    $centinelClient->add("MerchantId", CENTINEL_MERCHANT_ID);
    $centinelClient->add("TransactionPwd", CENTINEL_TRANSACTION_PWD);
    $centinelClient->add("TransactionType", "C");
    //$centinelClient->add('IPAddress', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $centinelClient->add('IPAddress', "127.0.0.1");

    // Standard cmpi_lookup fields
    $centinelClient->add('Amount', $_POST['Amount']);
    $centinelClient->add('CurrencyCode', "826"); // For example, GBP = 826, EUR = 978.
    $centinelClient->add('OrderNumber', rand(1111, 9999));

    // Payer Authentication specific fields
    $centinelClient->add('CardNumber', $_POST['CardNumber']);
    $centinelClient->add('CardExpMonth', $_POST['CardExpMonth']);
    $centinelClient->add('CardExpYear', $_POST['CardExpYear']);

    /*     * ******************************************************************************* */
    /*                                                                                */
    /* Send the XML Msg to the MAPS Server, the Response is the CentinelResponse Object */
    /*                                                                                */
    /*     * ******************************************************************************* */

    $centinelClient->sendHttp(CENTINEL_MAPS_URL, CENTINEL_TIMEOUT_CONNECT, CENTINEL_TIMEOUT_READ);
    $response = $centinelClient->response;
    echo '<h2>cmpi_lookup Response</h2>';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($response);
    echo '</pre>';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $response['ACSUrl']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(
                    array(
                        'PaReq' => $response['Payload'],
                        'TermUrl' => CENTINEL_TERM_URL,
                        'MD' => ''
                    )
            )
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response_IssuerAuthentication = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo '<h2>Issuer Authentication Response</h2>';
    print_r($response_IssuerAuthentication);

}
?>
```

Comment: What were your expectations?? I mean, i dont get your quesntion, are you facing some error, or were you expecting a different response?? And that localhost link, we cant access that, put it online somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your response @AjitKumarSingh Actually I should have got an array in issuer authentication response according to the documentation provided here.
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/ThreeDSecure/

Comment: Hey @AjitKumarSingh can you help me please?